# Devise & Rspec: User requires account activation in requests spec even after confirmed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, capybara, rspec2

I have the following code in my requests spec:

```
describe 'Poll' do
    subject { page }

    context 'as system admin' do
        let(:user) { Fabricate(:system_admin) }
            before { login user}

        it 'is accessible' do
            visit '/admin/poll'
            current_path.should == '/admin/poll'
        end

        describe 'sending poll' do

            it 'sends to all users' do
                save_and_open_page
            end
        end
    end
end
```

The login user doesn't seem to work even if the method seems to be working fine. I tried using `login user` inside the `it 'is accessible' do` block and that specs works fine if I do it that way. If I remove it from there and put it in a `before` block like above. The user doesn't stay signed in. I put in a `save_and_open_page` to debug and I get this notification in the page:

```
Your account was not activated yet. If a reset password link was sent to you, use that link to change your password.
```

I'm using Devise, RSpec, Capybara and Rails 3. I've also set user to `confirm!` in my Fabrication file. Below is how it looks:

```
Fabricator(:system_admin) do
    first_name { sequence(:first_name) { |n| "Person#{n}"} }
    last_name { sequence(:last_name) {|n| "#{n}" } }
    email { sequence(:email) { |n| "person_#{n}@example.com"} }
    password "foobar"
    password_confirmation "foobar"
    company_name { sequence(:company_name) { |n| "google#{n}" } }
    role "system_admin"

    after_create do |user|
        user.confirm!
      user.create_company
    end
end
```

**Question:** What could be the problem? How come the user isn't staying logged in and why do I get that message saying that I should activate my account? Isn't `user.confirm!` enough?

Answer (score 0):

could this be the problem?

Fabricate(:system_admin) != Fabricator(:system_admin)

Answer (score 0):

So if you debug your save_and_open_page and it tells you that the account is not activated it seemes your fabricate is not working properly. have you tried and debug that?

what does your save_and_open_page do? does it try to use the user for something? because I have experienced when defined with a let, if not touched the variable(user in this case) then it does no exist on that context. besides. whats the error when you run the specs like this on it "is acessible"? just says there is no user logged in?

so you can either stub your methods for login(for example if you have method called current_user that gives you the logged in user or something) or instead of using let, instiate like:

user = Fabricate(:system_admin)

but hey there is a lot of good advices here:

http://betterspecs.org/

it seems like your blocks context and describe are too complex. I am also not following this guidelines 100% but I think I should and you too would benefit from this.

let me know if you found out another reason why its not working!

Answer (score 0):

I think `before(:each)` should resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Add this Devise method:

```
confirmed_at { Time.now }
```

So your after_create method should looks like:

```
  after_create do |user|
      user.confirm!
      user.confirmed_at { Time.now }
      user.create_company
  end
```